# "vertical-align: middle" does not align to the middle in Firefox

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to align some text of different sizes vertically, however, Firefox displays the smaller text way above the middle.

CSS:

```
div.categoryLinks {
    margin: 1em 16px;
    padding: 0 4px;
    border-width: 1px 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #ece754;
    background: #f7f5b7;
    color: #a49f1c;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.4em;
}
div.categoryLinks em {
    font-size: 0.6em;
    font-style: normal;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="categoryLinks">
    <em>SECTION:</em>
    Page One &#183;
    Page Two &#183;
    <a href="link">Page Three</a>
</div>
```

Screenshot:
[image: screenshot]
<sub>(source: [doheth.co.uk](http://www.doheth.co.uk/files/valign.jpg))</sub>

**UPDATE**: just to be clear, I am aware more-or-less how `vertical-align` works, i.e. I already know the common misconceptions.

From more investigation, it seems like the simplest way to fix this issue is to wrap the larger text in a `span` and set `vertical-align` on that too. The two children of `.categoryLinks` then align relative to each other. Unless someone can show a better way without extra markup?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Vertical align elements in a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461/how-to-vertical-align-elements-in-a-div)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Vertical align only works as expected on table cells or `display: inline-block` elements.** If you want more information I suggest you read [Understanding vertical-align, or "How (Not) To Vertically Center Content"](http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html).

**Edit:** You've got something else going on because that works for me as is on Firefox. I even dropped the font size of SECTION: right down and it's still centered. Have you used Firebug to see what other CSS is affecting it?

This works as is:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
div.categoryLinks {
        margin: 1em 16px;
        padding: 0 4px;
        border-width: 1px 0;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #ece754;
        background: #f7f5b7;
        color: #a49f1c;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 1.4em;
}
div.categoryLinks em {
        font-size: 0.4em;
        font-style: normal;
        vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="categoryLinks">
        <em>SECTION:</em>
        Page One &#183;
        Page Two &#183;
        <a href="link">Page Three</a>
</div>
</body>
```

**Note:** section font size changed to 0.4em from original 0.6em to emphasize the point.

Comment: Just to add to this, you can try `display:table-cell` but I'm not sure what the browser support is for it.

Comment: He is talking about text-align: center CSS property, not about valign HTML property.

Comment: @buti-oxa: No he's not. He's talking about CSS vertical-align property

Comment: `vertical-align` also works on elements with `display:inline:block`.  So the first statement "Vertical align only works as expected on table cells." is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It walks through vertical alignment quite well.

Comment: @LiamWilliam Edited the post to say as much

Comment: There also is the flexbox solution now, see this answer on a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31078418/327074

Answer (score 2):

Vertical align is only supposed to apply to inline-block elements ( I think images are the only things that have this layout property by default), so to use it to position an inline element, first turn it into an inline block, then you can use margin and padding to position it similar to how you woudl a normal block element:

```
div.categoryLinks {
        margin: 1em 16px;
        padding: 0 4px;
        border-width: 1px 0;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #ece754;
        background: #f7f5b7;
        color: #a49f1c;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 1.4em;

}
div.categoryLinks em {
            font-size: 0.6em;

           display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:top;
        font-style: normal;
        padding: 2px 0 0 0;

}
```

You have to [tweak it a little for firefox 2](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2006/10/12/pain-with-inline-block/) though, but this is because of a raer example of firefox not supporting web standards. On the other hand you could not bother with the tweak as few people still use ffx2, and it's only a very minor design flaw.

Comment: Setting the em to inline block does not make a difference, it's still higher in Firefox.

Comment: but the point is that once you have display:inline-block you can then add some padding-top to the em too to push it down.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox is rendering correctly. The vertical-align property is inline, which means it doesn't apply to block elements like <div> (and <p>, etc). Try adding *display: inline* and see if that works.

Comment: Or, possibly, inline-block. Depending on the implementation (and cross-browser support) it might offer the best of both worlds.

Comment: He applies it to <em>SECTION:</em> which is already inline by default.

Comment: Setting the em to inline block does not make a difference, it's still higher in Firefox.

Comment: Whoops, you're right, buti-oxa. I need to learn to read more attentively.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issues just removing:

```
 white-space: nowrap;
```

from parent div.
I'm not sure why but with this rule added, Firefox doesn't apply the:

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. This works for me:

```
 <style type="text/css">
    div.parent {
         position: relative;
    }

    /*vertical middle and horizontal center align*/
    img.child {
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        margin: auto;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
    </style>

    <div class="parent">
        <img class="child"> 
    </div>
```